How to write test cases for file input using jest?
I am trying to write test cases for input type file but I am getting  empty file like this e.g. File {}
const PortNumberStep1 = ({
  state,
  phoneTypeData,
  phoneNumberProviderData,
  getValues,
  setPortingFile,
}: PortNumberStep1Props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const {
    values,
    errors,
    touched,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    setFieldValue,
    setFieldTouched,
    setFieldError,
  } = useFormikContext<AddPortNumberData>();

this is my handleChange function using formik
here we are setting values to the formik
const handleFileUploadChange = (event: any) => {
    if (event.target.files[0]) { // here I am getting File{}
      handleChange(event);
      setFieldValue("data.file", event.target.files[0]);
      setPortingFile(event.target.files[0]);
      setFieldTouched("data.file", false);
      setFieldError("data.file", "");
    }
  };

Here iconButton handle function
const onTabChange = (e: any) => {
    console.log("in onTabChange");
    if (e.type === "keydown") {
      console.log("in this if statmnent");
      uploadFileInputRef?.current?. Click();
    }
  };

return (
    <Root className={classes.mainDiv}>
      
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={8}>
          <input
            type="file"
            title="file"
            name="file"
            id="file"
            data-testid="input-field"
            ref={uploadFileInputRef}
            onChange={handleFileUploadChange}
            accept={fileTypeView.fileTypes}
            className={classes.fileInput}
          />
          <label htmlFor="file">
            <IconButton
              color="primary"
              component="span"
              size="large"
              onClick={onTabChange}
              data-testid="upload_file"
              className={classes.IconButton}
              aria-label={t("upload_file")}
            >
              <BackupIcon className={classes.ButtonSize} />
            </IconButton>
            {values?.data?.file?.name}
          </label>
          {errors?.data?.file && touched?.data?.file ? (
            <Typography color="error" className={classes.fileError}>
              {errors?.data?.file}
            </Typography>
          ) : null}
        </Grid>
      <Divider className="bottomDivider3" />
      <Grid container style={{ marginTop: "22px" }}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <div className={classes.buttonNext}>
            <CustomButton
              id="btn_next"
              label={t("accounts.next")}
              className="primaryButton"
              type="submit"
              onClick={submitForm} // formik onSumbit will call
            />

          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Root>
  );
};

export default PortNumberStep1;

// Test Case for uploading file
it("handles file upload correctly", async () => {
    const { queryByTestId, getByLabelText } = render(<MockPortNumbreStep1 />);

    const input = queryByTestId("input-field") as HTMLElement;

    const iconBtn = getByLabelText(t("upload_file"));
    fireEvent.click(iconBtn);

    const file = new File(["file content"], "file.pdf", {
      type: "application/pdf",
    });
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { files: [file] } });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(setPortingFile).toHaveBeenCalledWith(file);
    });
  });

after writing this test case. I am getting empty File {}
